# Updating a field which the Select query loop is based on

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a rough example of my mysql query (note: this is inside an other loop that goes through all users):

```
$query = db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = $uid AND reminded = 0');

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
  // send personalized reminder email to the user
  db.query('UPDATE table SET reminded = 1 WHERE userid = $uid');
}
```

The field `reminded` is set to 1 for all instances for that user.

My question is:
Is the query/while (fetch) already loaded into memory based on the original terms (`reminded = 0`), or will the remaining while loop behave according to those updates (`reminded = 1`)?

Let's say the user had 50 rows where `reminded` is 0, and the query selects those: Are they still existing with the value 0 in the rest of the while loop even though they were all changed to 1 during the loop?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but from the looks of it, this can become 1 query

Comment: do not mix mysql with php. Once you run the first query you transfer data from mysql to php. Then you run an update looping through a php array. The result is that if the select extract 50 records then you will run update 50 times. In short: the  answer to your query is "Yes"

Comment: @LelioFaieta Ah yes ok, that makes sense. I see it a bit clearer now. So I can't change what the query loop holds after it is loaded?

Comment: you should exit the loop, run the select again and loop on the new array. Your code makes little sense to me but I assume this is just an example of a different situation

Comment: Also this methode is prone to race conditions, well it seams you can't get corrupted data because of it.. This comment was more meant to make you aware off race conditions in general.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Scenario: User has 10 unread messages (reminded = 0). I want to go through them and remind the user ONE time and set reminded = 1 for all the other messages and ignore them so he/she doesn't get more than one reminder.

Comment: Your UPDATE query already does that. Just run that (once). You can add `AND reminded = 0` on the end to more precisely target only the exact rows (although it won't matter much if you update the other rows to a value they already have, but this clause makes it strictly more correct). You don't need the SELECT, unless it has another separate purpose (e.g. you want to display the data on-screen beforehand or something).

Comment: then move the update out of the loop. Attach it to an event of displaying the messages

Comment: Like @ADyson also said Using `UPDATE table SET reminded = 1 WHERE userid = $uid AND reminded = 0` should do the same thing.. Beware off SQL injections in your code also.

Comment: @ADyson the select i assume is to display the messages (that's why the loop). The update should be binded to an event like click to display

Comment: The code is a very rough example of how my code for a email reminder sender looks like. It has to go through not-reminded, and only remind ONE time about ANY unread messages. Dang it's hard to explain ;) but it helps me understand what I want better I guess

Comment: "It has to go through not-reminded"...no, it doesn't need to loop through them at all (unless you need to show them on-screen first, or do some other unrelated processing of the rows). That's our point. For the purpose of setting the "reminded" field to 1 for all un-reminded messages, your UPDATE query is already sufficient - it will operate on _all_ those rows in one single statement. That's the beauty of SQL's set-based command structure. Possibly you might need to select the first un-reminded email and send the reminder about it, but you certainly don't need to select _all_ of them for that

Comment: @ADyson I do need the loop for doing other stuff and sending out the reminder to each user though (it's for a cron job). Maybe I just need to re-check for each iteration if any reminder was sent to that user, and skip sending if so

Comment: "sending out the reminder to each user" ...your loop is specific to a single user (the SQL SELECT statement selects by the user ID). Maybe you have a _different_ loop for checking each user, but you don't need the loop you've shown here, unless you can clarify what "other stuff" is, exactly.

Comment: @ADyson Ah yes, sorry. That loop is inside an other loop that goes through each user. I appreciate your help, I think I'm closer to seeing how I can do it

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = $uid AND reminded = 0 LIMIT 1` will get you the first un-reminded message for that user. Then just fetch that single row from the results, and use it to generate the email. After that, then run `UPDATE table SET reminded = 1 WHERE userid = $uid AND reminded = 0` once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code and SQL you have is only an example (because you should update directly without a php loop).

The fetch on the `table` rows is executed on the DB row by row.

So, if one or more of these rows are updated in the while loop, in next iterations you will retrive and update (again) the previous updated rows.

I think that you have to be careful "only" if you are updating a field that is part of an index or a field that is used in the SQL to retrieve data (es. a field used in the `ORDER BY`, etc.).

Comment: *"I think that you have to be careful "only" if you are updating a field that is part of an index or a field that is used in the SQL to retrieve data (es. a field used in the ORDER BY, etc.)."* Yes if you don't want a index rebuild after every `UPDATE` you should use a transaction and commit it.